# Azure DevOps Server 2019: Number of covered lines instead of percentage

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Just moved from TFS 2017 to [Azure DevOps Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019?view=azure-devops). Build runs fine and I can see code coverage results in percentage as you can see in the image.

[image]

Is there a way to see the number of covered lines instead of percentage (like in TFS 2017)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Server 2019: Number of covered lines instead of percentage

According to the [issue 3027](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/3027), that style is disabled due to some security restrictions.

We could download code coverage result from Code Coverage tab. **However**, the code coverage tab is missing on current release, Azure devops team reported that this feature would be available in the next release.

Ticket: [Code coverage tab missing in Azure DevOps Server](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/578111/code-coverage-tab-missing-in-azure-devops-server.html).

As workaround, you could add copy files and publish build results steps , then you can download coverage result file from Artifacts.

Hope this helps.